# git-remote-https died of signal 6 - when pulling from repo

Tags: git, github

Recently I committed some larger files to a repo of mine. While doing so, I increased the `http.postBuffer` to `524288000`. Usually, when I do this, after I’m done I decrease it back to `5242`. Last time, I forgot, and when I tried to `git pull` today I got the error from the title. (I need to pull because I have changes on the remote that I pushed from another machine) Could this somehow be causing the issue? I don’t think so, because I also tried increasing the `http.bufferSize` even more and I didn’t manage to get it to work.

I downloaded the repo manually from GitHub and it was only `5MB`.

I also tried to `git clone` the repo but I got the same error.

I Googled the issue but none of the solutions worked. What could be the problem?

Just for reference, I’m on macOS.

EDIT: I never managed to solve the issue. I had to switch to using SSH instead of HTTP.

Comment: First of all, [you should not need to set `http.postBuffer`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#http-postbuffer) and it has no effect on fetches or clones.  Try unsetting it completely, and then include the entire output of the operation as a text block by editing your question.  There is probably some other problem going on, and that text will be helpful.